# Why do I get an error when deploying firebase functions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When trying to deploy the template function after initialising firebase functions, I keep getting: HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors. Any ideas on what's going on?

Here's the relevant code.

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase does not expect named exports ( `export const ...`) and instead expects an `exports` object containing the function to run. Change it to this: `exports.helloWorld = ...`. Furthermore, this had been [a recurrent issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1317) in the past by attempting to use older versions of the Firebase CLI. Try updating it by running `npm i -g firebase-tools@latest`.